# 画像の一部を pointer-events: none; で反応しないようにすることは可能か？

Tags: css

以下の画像の左側50pxだけを `pointer-events: none;` で反応しないようにしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

ダミーを作ってリンクを貼らないで作るしかないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

> 以下の画像の左側50pxだけを `pointer-events: none;` で反応しないようにしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

「`img` 要素の親要素に `a` 要素がある状態で、 `a` 要素によるページ遷移やカーソル変化などのポインターイベントを一部分でのみ無効にしたい」という状況だと質問文から推測しました。

そのような場合には、 `a` 要素でのポインターイベントを無効にした上で、 `a` 要素の擬似要素でのポインターイベントを有効にし、それを画像の任意の箇所に重ねることで、画像の一部分のみポインターイベントが有効になっているような動作を実現出来ます。

しかし、厳密には画像への一部のポインターイベントだけ有効化 (または無効化) するということは出来ず、この方法では**あくまでも画像へのポインターイベントは無効化された状態**になっています。もしこの方法では条件を満たせず、画像への一部のポインターイベントだけ有効化 (または無効化) する必要があるのであれば、 JavaScript を用いる必要があります。

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

a::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdQOs.png">
</a>
```